# How do I check a windows directory for changes without running a background process?

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems, monitoring, ntfs

I would like to write an application that, when run, checks to see if a directory has changed. Because I plan to deploy to various enterprise environments, I have the following additional requirements:

- Application will have have user (non-administrator) permissions
- Application may not be running continuously since the last check (User or system may close the application, make changes to the directory, then restart it and I would like to be able to detect those changes)

The two approaches Windows provides seem to each not quite match my requirements:

[Directory Change Notifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365261(v=vs.85).aspx) require the application to be running all the time.

[Change Journals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363798(v=vs.85).aspx) seem to require administrator privileges (and also track the entire volume which might be overkill)

Does anyone familiar with Windows or NTFS have any good ideas?

Comment: You basically listed the available options. Active monitoring and historic log traversal

Comment: Would it meet your requirements to simply check the timestamps on the files? You'll miss a lot of things (e.g. a file copied into the directory instead of created there), but if the files are always new (e.g. it's an upload staging directory on a web server), timestamps should do the trick.

Comment: When saving a copy of the directory metadata also keep in mind that there are [alternate-data-streams in NTFS](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/105763/how-to-use-ntfs-alternate-data-streams).

Comment: You could also compile a DB of file hashes and check it every now and then while the software is running. I bet Dropbox does something similar.